# How to store objects in an array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am at a stage where I have gone beyond syntax errors so I am finding it difficult regarding why at times my code does not behave correctly and this is one of those times and would love your guidance on this.

Code snippet follows:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    for (int i = 0; i < eventStatus.length; i++)
        eventStatus[i] = new EventStatus();

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    boolean proceed = false;
    boolean finished = false;

    while (!finished) {

        //System.out.println(eventImpl.getEventType());
        if (("INITIAL".equals(eventImpl.getEventType())) && (!eventStatus[0].isHasOccured())) {

            eventStatus[0].setHasOccured(true);
            eventStatus[0].setHasSent(true);
            eventStatus[0].setEventImpl(eventImpl);
            System.out.println("one");
            consumeEvent(eventStatus[0].getEventImpl());

            if (eventStatus[1].isHasOccured()) {
                System.out.println("two");
                eventStatus[1].setHasSent(true);
                consumeEvent(eventStatus[1].getEventImpl());

                proceed = true;
            } else {
                proceed = false;
            }

            if ((eventStatus[2].isHasOccured()) && proceed) {
                System.out.println("three");
                eventStatus[2].setHasSent(true);
                consumeEvent(eventStatus[2].getEventImpl());

                proceed = true;
            } else {
                proceed = false;
            }

            if ((eventStatus[3].isHasOccured()) && proceed) {
                System.out.println("four");
                eventStatus[3].setHasSent(true);
                consumeEvent(eventStatus[3].getEventImpl());

                proceed = true;
            } else {
                proceed = false;
            }

            if ((eventStatus[4].isHasOccured()) && proceed) {
                System.out.println("five");
                eventStatus[4].setHasSent(true);
                consumeEvent(eventStatus[4].getEventImpl());

                proceed = true;
            } else {
                proceed = false;
            }

            System.out.println("INITIAL Here");

        }

        if (("CREATING".equals(eventImpl.getEventType())) && (!eventStatus[1].isHasOccured())) {

            eventStatus[1].setHasOccured(true);
            eventStatus[1].setEventImpl(eventImpl);

            System.out.println("CREATING Here");

        }

        if (("CREATED".equals(eventImpl.getEventType())) && (!eventStatus[2].isHasOccured())) {

            eventStatus[2].setHasOccured(true);
            eventStatus[2].setEventImpl(eventImpl);

            System.out.println("CREATED Here");

        }
        if (("CLOSING".equals(eventImpl.getEventType())) && (!eventStatus[3].isHasOccured())) {

            eventStatus[3].setHasOccured(true);
            eventStatus[3].setEventImpl(eventImpl);

            System.out.println("CLOSING Here");
        }

        if (("CLOSED".equals(eventImpl.getEventType())) && (!eventStatus[4].isHasOccured())) {

            eventStatus[4].setHasOccured(true);
            eventStatus[4].setEventImpl(eventImpl);

            System.out.println("CLOSED Here");
        }

        if (!finished) {
            eventImpl.setEventType(EventImpl.eventTypes.values()[randomGenerator.nextInt(5)]);
        }
    }
}
```

And the helper class:

```
public class EventStatus {

    private boolean hasOccured = false;
    private boolean hasSent = false;
    private EventImpl eventImpl;

    public boolean isHasOccured() {
        return hasOccured;
    }

    public boolean isHasSent() {
        return hasSent;
    }

    public void setHasOccured(boolean hasOccured) {
        this.hasOccured = hasOccured;
    }

    public void setHasSent(boolean hasSent) {
        this.hasSent = hasSent;
    }

    public EventImpl getEventImpl() {
        return eventImpl;
    }

    public void setEventImpl(EventImpl eventImpl) {
        this.eventImpl = eventImpl;
    }

}
```

The problem being while I am trying to store an instance of EventImpl class for each 'If's when I run the code the stored objects do not run but instead the default for the 'if' object gets executed for each condition met.

For example:

```
CLOSED Here
CREATED Here
CREATING Here
CLOSING Here
one
Event ID: 7573f0fe-d848-4049-8d5c-28fcbf5c8497 Event: INITIAL
two
Event ID: 7573f0fe-d848-4049-8d5c-28fcbf5c8497 Event: INITIAL
three
Event ID: 7573f0fe-d848-4049-8d5c-28fcbf5c8497 Event: INITIAL
four
Event ID: 7573f0fe-d848-4049-8d5c-28fcbf5c8497 Event: INITIAL
five
Event ID: 7573f0fe-d848-4049-8d5c-28fcbf5c8497 Event: INITIAL
INITIAL Here
```

Each of these INITIAL except for one should really be stating the object previously stored in my helper class.

So could you please tell me how do I get this done please?

```
@Override
public synchronized void consumeEvent (Event theEvent) {

    System.out.println("Event ID: " + theEvent.getEventId() + " Event: " + theEvent.getEventType());
}
```

Comment: Since I can't see where your program is printing out anything that begins with `Event ID:`, I can't tell why it isn't printing out what you want.

Comment: All your elements look like they're correctly getting their `eventImpl` set to whatever the `eventImpl` is that you're starting with. But whether that's the right `eventImpl`, only you can tell us.

Comment: General thought: I think one of your main problems is, that you are doing everything in one giant method (>100 lines), and on top of that, inside a while loop. Try to break down your program into small, understandable pieces (methods and classes), and you should run into less problems.

Comment: The one, two, three, four, five are distinct events that were recorded previously but when I print it out it only states the 'INITIAL' state for all the other events as well.

Comment: @ Kulu Limpa: I intend to do just that once it works first. :-)

Comment: The only way that the instance variable `eventImpl` could vary over the scope of one execution of the `run()` method is if the `consumeEvent()` or some other thread method directly or indirectly modifies it.  If that's not happening then perhaps it would explain your result.  You haven't presented that method, so we can't say much more.

Comment: @John Bollinger: i have provided the consumeEvent() above. What you said made me think. Could you please explain some more please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one `Event` (`EventImpl`) object involved -- whatever is stored in the `eventImpl` instance variable of the class containing those methods.  At each iteration of the loop, you assign a reference to that object to a property of one of the elements of your `eventStatus` array, and you set that same object's `eventType` property to a random value, but neither action creates a new object.

After you eventually set the type to "INITIAL", the program goes through and consumes the `EventImpl` stored in each of one or more elements of your `eventStatus` array, but every element that contains one contains *the same* one.

It's hard for me to tell what you are actually trying to do here, or why you are approaching it as you do, but the program's reported behavior is exactly as its code leads me to expect.

Comment: that explains the behaviour. Much thanks! Now I have to figure out how to fix it. Could you provide more insight? (You have already done a lot though).

Comment: I can't advise you on specifics of how to fix it without some idea of what it's supposed to do.  Generally speaking, though, it looks like perhaps you want to instantiate a new `EventImpl` instance in your `if (!finished)` block instead of modifying the existing one.

Comment: That is an excellent tip. Except in this case I need to maintain the same Event ID theEvent.getEventId() and for each ID it has to go through a collection of event types before it can be terminated. That is why I am looking for a way to maintain all the occurred events. Events can happen in any order but it is my task to order them in the right order and then the thread ends. Any more helpful hints?